# Angular 2 Component variable not updating in function called in imported component

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working on Component1 and I'm importing Component2 into Component1's html and passing a Component1 function (component1.function2()) into it.

My problem is that when that function changes a Component1 variable, it doesn't show in Component1 scope. So component1.function2() **read** Component1 object and the values in it but it cannot **write** to it.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!-- Component 1, the main component --> 
<div>
    <h2>{{ component_variable }}</h2> defined in Component1 

    <button (click)="change_var()">Change Variable</button> <!-- Changes the value of component_variable successfully -->

    <!-- Component2. Notice change_from_component2(), defined in Component1  -->
    <angular4-paystack
        [key]="public_key"
        [email]="email"
        [amount]="amount"
        [ref]="ref"
        [class]="'btn btn-success'"
        (callback)="change_from_component2($event)"
        >Pay Now</angular4-paystack>
</div>
```

JS:

```
/*
  Component1.js
*/
export class Component1 implements OnInit {

//defines a bunch of variables including:
component_variable: any = "Something good";

//skipping past constructors and a bunch of other things

change_var(){
   this.component_variable = "Something better";   //works
}
change_from_component2(e){
   //when this is called from component2, none of the changes made reflects in the component1 scope
   console.log(this.component_variable); // 'Something good', except if you've clicked the Change Variable, then 'Something Better'.
   console.log(this); // logs Component1 object. So it definitely sees Component1

   this.component_variable = "Something even better";   //doesn't work, this function doesn't touch Component1
}
```

How do I effect this change?

Comment: How do you call the function `change_from_component` in component 2?

Comment: I didn't build component2 but it's a callback function, and it's executes properly. Problem is that it change the Component1 scope.

Comment: Is `callback` of component with selector `angular4-paystack` being fired? That is probably where the code is "hung up" or there is another error in your code that you might be able to see if you open your development console in the browser. If you want more help **you will have to show the relevant code** in the missing component with selector `angular4-paystack`.

Comment: @Igor it doesn't hang. It just doesn't update the component1 variables. I can console.log(e) and it works perfectly, but none of the changes goes out to the component1 scope

Comment: As I stated you have to **share the code of that component**. We (*as far as I know anyway*) are not a part of the NSA and do not have access to your PC and cannot see the code that you have questions about. We (*again, as far as I know*) prefer not to answer questions based on assumptions (ie. making guesses).

Comment: @Igor https://github.com/ashinzekene/angular4-paystack

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure that `this` is pointing to your component in your event handler `change_from_component2`? Add `console.log(this.component_variable)` as the first line of code to see if that prints out the expected original string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157358/discussion-between-ikey-and-igor).